# Tangent space of an orbit

Tags: differential-geometry, group-actions

Let $G$ be a Lie group acting on a manifold $M$. Fix a point $m \in M$ and we denote by $a_m$ the map given by $$a_m : G \rightarrow M, g \rightarrow g.m $$ the action of of $G$ on $m$.

I read that we have that  $T_m O_m = Im({(a_m)}_*)$, where $T_m O_m$ is the tangent space of the orbit $O_m$ and ${(a_m)}_*$ denotes the differential at the identity of the map $a_m$.

It easy to see that $Im({(a_m)}_*) \subset  T_m O_m$, but I don't know how to prove the other inclusion ?

Comment: Hint: show that if $v \in T_mO_m$ and  if $\gamma(t)$ is a smooth path in $O_m$ with $\gamma(0) = m$ and $\gamma'(0)=v$, then there exists a smooth path in $G$ with $g(0) = e$ and $\gamma(t) = g(t)\cdot m$. Conclude by differentiating this last equality.

Comment: @Didier, thank you so much for your comment! I have just one question: how can we prove that the curve $g(t)$ is of the form $exp(tX)$, for some $X \in \mathfrak{g}$ ? I'm saying this because $Im{(a_m)}_* =\lbrace X_M(m), m\in M\rbrace  $ , where $X_M(m)= {\frac{d}{dt}}_{|t=0}exp(tX).m$.